# Java Spring: localeChangeInterceptor and subdomains

Tags: java, spring, multilingual

I have a Spring MVC webapp and want to do this (example):

- Request to subdomain **en.foo.com** -> language should be **English**
- Request to subdomain **es.foo.com** -> language should be **Spanish**

I already use the `localeChangeInterceptor` to change the language by URL parameter on request, and this works (adding a parameter e.g. ?lang=en to my URLs).

But what is the best way to have *language-specific subdomains* with Spring? I searched the web and Spring documentation, but have yet to find an answer.

I think it could work like this:

1. Intercept any request
2. Determine used subdomain
3. Decide which language/locale should be used and set it like the `localeChangeInterceptor` does

If this is the way to go, I could use a hint where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to implement your own [LocaleResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html).

The LocaleResolver.resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest) method is what Spring uses to determine which Locale to use from the MessageSource.  You can extract the subdomain from the request and return the desired Locale.

Comment: I have written my own `LocaleResolver` with the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` as fallback. What doesn't work now is the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` - it calls my `setLocale` method but in there `response.setLocale(locale)` doesn't change the locale for the response somehow. How does the standard `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` do this? It does not implement a `setLocale` method at all - I'm confused.

Comment: You have to use `SessionLocaleResolver` as fallback in your `LocaleResolver` and everything works.